# How to hide symbol names in executable (from asm code)

Tags: assembly, nasm, ld

I have a small "hello world" program in asm. After compiling and linking, I can see all the names I used for my variables and labels in the final elf file (opened with text editor). Why ? Shouldn't variables and so on be replaced by static or relative addresses ?
How can I hide this info ?

I am using nasm on ubuntu x86 64 : `nasm -f elf64 hello.asm && ld -o a hello.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is debug information. You can remove it from the object file using the command [strip](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strip).

Answer (score 1):

Stripping can also be accomplished in link time by calling `--strip-all` flag, in your case:
`nasm -f elf64 hello.asm && ld -o a hello.o --strip-all`.

This will remove ALL of the symbols from the output file, if you wish to remove only the debug ones you can use `--strip-debug`.

You can read about more options here: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html